# Desempenho: switch ou if alinhado?

Tags: desempenho, if, switch

Independente de linguagem, o `switch` tem melhor desempenho que um alinhamento de `if`s?

Se sim: por que?

```
if
  ...
elif
  ...
elif
  ...
else
  ...
end

switch
  case
    ...
  case
    ...
  case
    ...
  else
    ...
end
```

Comment: Infelizmente eu não me recordo onde eu li que deve-se evitar ELSEIF sempre que possível pois durante a interpretação do código cada uma das condições é testada antes. Porém, na minha concepção, é impossível responde a esse tipo de pergunta sem conhecer a fundo cada linguagem.

Comment: Não existe muita diferença pra falar a verdade, o desempenho é semelhante. Da uma olhada nesse link: [If Ou Switch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767821/is-else-if-faster-than-switch-case)

Comment: "Independente de linguagem" é difícil de responder, pois depende de como ela implementa o `switch`. Ela *poderia* comparar o argumento com cada `case`, ela *poderia* "empilhar" o argumento (se for uma arquitetura de pilha) e comparar "o topo da pilha" com cada caso, ela poderia usar um *lookup table*... Que eu saiba, na maioria das linguagens comuns a diferença de performance é pequena ou negligível, mas não posso afirmar com certeza sem: a) testar; b) conferir a implementação (i.e. ver como é gerado o código de máquina).

Comment: De que linguagem está falando? Isto não pode ser respondido com certeza para todas as linguagens. Só suposições podem ser feitas. Seria Python? Até agora não gostei das respostas postadas. Algumas até fazem suposições simplistas e flertam com o erro.

Comment: Existe uma forma técnica de explicar isso ... ?

Comment: @HarryPotter Benchmarks.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Em todas as linguagens?

Comment: @bigown Se pararmos para pensar, a maneira técnica de explicar performance em meio à tecnologias é com *benchmarks* – nenhuma linguagem segue um fluxo de performance lógico, portanto, se fizermos um benchmark de todas as linguagens então sim, teremos uma explicação técnica para todas elas.

Comment: @GuilhermeOderdenge Concordo. Parece não haver espaço suficiente aqui para todos eles.

Comment: Uma idéia então seria colocar uma pergunta para cada linguagem porque aqui ficaria muito amplo

Comment: Javascript não possui elif, end, acerte a sintaxe então. Mas não sei como vai ficar todas as respostas que foram dadas sem saber que era JS. @Bacco também conhecia *aninhado* para isto. Se achar alguma coisa, compartilhe o resultado :)

Comment: Eu sempre chamei isso de "cadeia de ifs"... De fato, embora o código não esteja aninhado, a semântica é equivalente a um aninhamento dentro do `else`. Exemplo: `if { ... } else { if { ... } else { if { ... } else { ... } } }`

Comment: @Bacco Eu queria dizer "aninhado" mesmo, por ser equivalente ao código que o mgibsonbr postou.

Comment: @Bacco `1)` O "L" foi um erro de digitação. O fato de eles ficarem alinhados com o `elif` foi coincidência. `2)` Eu estou bem tranquilo, não sei como você achou que não. hahaha =)

Answer (score 2):

```
if a == 0
    ...
elsif a == 1
    ...
elsif a == 2
    ...
else
    ...
end
```

É identico em semântica a:

```
switch a
case 0
    ...
case 1
    ...
case 2
    ...
default
    ...
end
```

Sendo assim, uma boa ferramenta vai gerar o mesmo código ou código equivalente em qualquer sentido mensurável. Se isso não é verdade para o seu caso específico (talvez alguma característica da linguagem), então esse caso tem que ser visto em particular.

A única exceção clara da regra é se o seu `a` não for uma expressão simples, como uma leitura de variável, mas algo complexo que envolve executar código. Por exemplo:

```
if prod.getProductType() == 50
    ...
elsif prod.getProductType() == 78
    ...
end
```

Pode claramente executar a função mais de uma vez, enquanto que no caso do switch isso não aconteceria. (Claro, uma otimização pode concluir que a função é pura e chamar uma vez só, mas isso não vem a caso). Se você precisa fazer alguma computação para obter o valor que vai testar, melhor usar switch. Caso contrário, os dois são equivalentes. Use aquele que achar mais legível.

Um ponto a levar em consideração é que a transformação de um switch em um jump table (mais eficiente) é muito mais fácil de ser feita pelo compilador do que partindo de ifs. Portanto, se são muitos casos e possibilidades, pode ser mais vantajoso usar um switch. Note que isso depende também da linguagem.